# Add Vote of Product in database

Tags: sql, t-sql

On a database I am saving Baskets bought by Users:

```
USERS
Id
Name

BASKETS
Id
UserId
Name
```

Each basket is a selection of predefined Packages:

```
BASKET_PACKAGES
BasketId   
PackageId

PACKAGES
PackageId
Name
```

Each package is a selection of predefined Products:

```
PACKAGE_PRODUCTS
PackageId
ProductId

PRODUCTS
Id
Name
```

In each basket I need to define a VOTE value for each product.

Each user might vote a product differently in different occasions, e.g., in different baskets.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the table:

```
create table basket_product_vote (
  basket_id int not null,
  product_id int not null,
  voted_on timestamp not null,
  vote_value int not null,
  constraint fk1_basket foreign key (basket_id) 
    references basket (id),
  constraint fk2_product foreign key (product_id) 
    references product (id)
);
```

The `user_id` could be included, but I decided not to add it by default since in principle it can be obtained using the foreign key.

Also, you will probably want to create extra indexes to speed up searches.

Answer (score 2):

Create entity like below

```
BasketVote
BasketVoteId PK
BasketId    FK
ProductId   FK
UserId      FK
Vote
```

You can also use PackageProductId instead of ProductId, its all based on your requirement.